# How to rotate textures? Or how to set texture coordinates?

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm currently trying to texture a road with textures from CC0Textures. I've got an asphalt texture and a road lines texture both Principled BDSF with their own colour, roughness and normal maps. The only problem is, is that the road lines come out facing the wrong way. 
[image]

My node setup looks like this.
[image]

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/vector/mapping.html

Comment: Hey, I've tried this but all it does is just make it disappear. Though I don't exactly know how to use it :/

Comment: You have to plug a texture coordinate node in its vector input.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/texture_coordinate.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Mapping" node: with this node you can edit scale, location and rotation of your texture. Just add it to the node tree of your shader and connect the "Vector" output to the "Vector" socket of your image nodes (try only mask first, and if it doesn't work try with both mask and color/rgh/nrm maps). "Mapping" node needs the "Texture coordinate" node (Shift+A > Input > Texture coordinate).

But I would suggest to properly UV unwrap your plane, so the direction is set in the UV editor once:

[image: By rotating the UVs you can change the rotation of the texture projection]

[image]